# Тайное голосование с подтверждением личности

Tags: криптография, теория

Представьте цифровое голосование. Голосующие должны быть уверены, что их голос не изменится без их ведома, при этом их голос будет анонимный. Государство же в свою очередь должно быть уверено, что голосующий имеет право на голосование. На ум приходит блокчейн, но как гарантировать анонимность и проверять личность голосовавшего???

Вопрос: существуют ли какие-нибудь криптографические механизмы, которые могут считывать результат, без раскрытия голосовавшего, но подтверждающее право голосования? Не слежу пристально за развитием криптографии, и вдруг прогресс достиг невиданных чудес...

В пример привожу спам фильтр по шифрованному сообщению. Фильтр не знает содержимого письма, но может вычленить спам по сигнатуре спама.

Comment: Вроде спам-фильтр как раз знает содержимое письма.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я читал не эту стать, но подход там был тот же https://habr.com/ru/post/230645/

Comment: Не про криптографию. Надеюсь, `их голос не изменится без их ведома` эквивалентен `их голос принят верно`. Тогда можно было бы разрешить голосовать только **одному** участнику в **один** момент времени. Он проходит регистрацию, получает идентификатор (система сверяет, должен ли голос быть засчитан) и в любой момент голосования отправляет его вместе со своим голосом. По изменению счётчика можно судить о корректности принятия голоса, и никто, кроме проголосовавшего, не будет знать, кто и как проголосовал. Участников также можно разбить на зоны, каждая зона имеет собственный счётчик.

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, не совсем понял как это работает. Сервер будет знать, что в момент времени M проголосовал идентификатор X. А идентификатор Х связан вот с таким человеком. Анонимности нет.

Comment: @ArchDemon, что значит связан с человеком? Я считаю, это значит, что только по нему можно определить, кто отдал свой голос, поэтому идентификатор необязательно должен быть связан с участником голосования. Участник проходит регистрацию (до начала голосования), передавая свою персональную информацию (большая часть её известна только участнику), регистрирующий сервер односторонне шифрует полученную информацию и возвращает зашифрованную информацию как идентификатор. Так как получить обратно персональную информацию невозможно, идентификатор оказывается не связанным с человеком.

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, вот у вас уже сервер знает, что персональные данные привязаны к идентификатором. А идентификатор связан с голосом. Делаем вывод, что персональные данные связаны с голосом. Сервер будет знать кто и как проголосовал. Если любой может зарегистрировать, то такой вариант не подходит. Человек может зарегистрироваться дважды, человек может зарегистрироваться, но не обладать правом голоса, но всё равно проголосовать

Comment: @ArchDemon, вы никогда не сможете убедить сомневающихся, что электронная система "играет честно".

Comment: @avp, это и не нужно делать. Главное чтобы с технической и программной стороны было всё честно. И главный тут вопрос " а возможно ли в принципе такое"

Comment: @ArchDemon, такое в принципе невозможно, компетентные органы заставят сделать бэкдор

Comment: @ArchDemon если доказывать честность системы не нужно и система имеет базу идентификаторов для проверки голосов, то просто удаляйте эту базу при завершении голосования.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, никто из простых смертных не заставит государство удалить базу результатов голосов.

Comment: @avp, опять же не про это речь. Речь о технической и программной возможности сделать цифровое голосование анонимным.

Comment: @ArchDemon, тогда подробно объясните, что означает в вашем понимании анонимность. Кто именно не должен иметь возможность узнать как проголосовал Х? Скажем, root-а (в винде у него наверняка есть аналог)  без применения релевантных организационных мероприятий такой возможности принципиально не получится лишить.

Comment: @avp, зашёл бы в чат что ли, а то вы тут кругами ходите.

Comment: @ArchDemon понятно что не заставит (и я сказал про базу идентификаторов, а не результатов голосов), но вы же говорите, что система честная и доказывать честность не нужно. Если она не честная и ею управляют заведомо мошенники (государство), то какая разница, возможно ли это технически? Например, если биткоины перейдут под контроль какого-нибудь государства, то они тут же превратятся в обычную валюту.

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, поэтому нужна такая система, которая позволит государству доверять голосующим, а голосующим доверять государству. И доверии тут будет  основано не на вере, а на невозможности программно и технически подорвать авторитет и того, и другого

Comment: Это конечно фигня по сравнению с Вашем алгоритмом, но может ответите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1367392/423786

Answer (score 13):

Такое голосование можно реализовать при помощи [blind signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature).

Если на пальцах, то операция выглядит так:

1. Алиса заполняет бюллетень и запаковывает бумажку в конверт с окошком. Голос Алисы в окошке не виден.
2. Алиса предъявляет конверт Бобу, аутентификатору. Тот сличает документы Алисы с базой избирателей и, если всё ок, ставит штамп "подтверждено" на бюллетень через окошко на конверте. Заодно аутентификатор делает отметку в базе избирателей, что Алиса проголосовала.

Ключевой момент всей схемы: аутентификатор не видит содержимое бюллетеня, а пользователь не может перенести штамп на другой бюллетень. То есть Боб заверяет легитимность листа бумаги, на котором напечатан бюллетень, ничего не зная о содержимом.

Второй важный момент: в отметке аутентификатора нет информации, которая позволила бы связать заверенный лист с Алисой. После снятия конверта бюллетень становится анонимным. Даже аутентификатор не сможет сказать, кому принадлежит бюллетень.

3. Алиса вынимает бюллетень из конверта и уничтожает конверт. Затем отправляет бюллетень по обезличенному каналу связи (например, бросает в урну). Другими словами, получатель бюллетеня (местная избирательная комиссия), не знает, кому принадлежит поданный лист бумаги.
4. При подсчете голосов учитываются только бюллетени с штампом "подтверждено". Если на заполненном бюллетене нет штампа Боба, он считается фальшивым. Если на листе бумаги со штампом не бюллетень, а что-то иное, он игнорируется.

Так как схема не допускает переноса отметки с бюллетеня на бюллетень, счетная комиссия может быть уверена, что бюллетени принадлежат только аутентифицированным пользователям. Так как после снятия конверта теряется идентификационная информация, никто не сможет установить связь между бюллетенем и Алисой.

Схема позволяет:

1. Обеспечить проверку права голосовать. Это делает Боб.
2. Обеспечить анонимность голосования. Это благодаря тому, что конверт, который мог бы потенциально связать бюллетень с Алисой, уничтожается.
3. Обеспечить правило "один человек - один голос". Это тоже делает Боб.
4. Если после голосования все бюллетени вывешиваются в открытый доступ, можно провести аудит подсчета голосов и результатов голосования.

У схемы есть недостатки. Прежде всего, в схеме существенно доверие к аутентификатору в том, что он не подписывает бюллетени от несуществующих избирателей. Другими словами, схема не защищена от вбросов.

Это решается введением нескольких независимых центров аутентификации - Алиса ставит штампы в каждом, и счетная комиссия учитывает только бюллетени, подтверждённые во всех центрах.

Кроме того, на текущий момент есть только один класс реализаций. Они все реализованы на RSA, и для них известны различные атаки.

Существуют и другие схемы. Ссылки можете найти в [обзоре](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/31227263.pdf), раздел 5. Обзор несколько бестолковый, но пойдёт для начального ознакомления.

## Примерный алгоритм blind signature

Схем того, как можно использовать blind signature для голосования, много разных.

Ниже приведена схема с предварительным заверением бюллетеня. В этой схеме бюллетень заполняется и заверяется заранее, а заполненный бюллетень публикуется в открытом виде после истечения срока голосования. Можно бюллетень публиковать сразу, но в этом случае подсчет голосов будет вестись в реальном времени, и может получиться что-то вроде давления на избирателей.

0. **Алиса делает свой выбор** и оформляет его в виде документа-бюллетеня `v`. Что-нибудь вроде `v = {"election-id":"XYZ","vote": "1","nonce":"deadbeef"}`. Конкретный бинарный формат не принципиален. В бюллетене приведен идентификатор голосования, выбор избирателя и случайный нонс, чтобы избежать коллизий хэш сумм.

   Идентификатор голосования необходим как защита от replay-атак, чтобы супостаты не смогли проголосовать от имени Алисы в последующих выборах.
1. Алиса вычисляет `hv = hash(v)` и особым образом его шифрует одноразовым ключом: `m = E_alice(hv)`. Типа, упаковала заполненный бюллетень в непрозрачный конвертик.
2. Сообщение `m` Алиса предъявляет аутентификатору, Бобу. Способ "предъявления" в данном случае непринципиален. Например, перед выборами Алиса сгенерировала приватный ключ и подписала соответствующий ему публичный ключ в Центризбиркоме. Читай, получила сертификат избирателя. Для предъявления аутентификатору Алиса подписывает `m` своим приватным ключом и прикладывает к подписи свой сертификат избирателя.

   Боб проверяет личность Алисы, удостоверяется, что Алиса первый раз участвует в голосовании `XYZ` и строит слепую подпись -- особым образом шифрует своим приватным ключом `m`: `bs = E_bob(m)`. Типа, Боб ставит штампик "Подтверждено" на бюллетень Алисы. Заодно сохраняет в базу данных подтверждение о том, что Алиса проголосовала - подписанный Алисой запрос.

   **Теперь следите за руками**. "Особым образом шифрует" означает, что порядок шифрования можно переставлять. Схема шифрования `E` такова, что `E_bob(E_alice(hv)) == E_alice(E_bob(hv))`. Это очень, **очень** сильное свойство. Навскидку я могу вспомнить только одну схему с таким свойством - RSA.
3. **Благодаря коммутативности выбранной операции шифрования** Алиса расшифровывает слепую подпись (делает unblind): `s = D_alice(bs) = D_alice(E_bob(E_alice(hv))) = D_alice(E_alice(E_bob(hv))) = E_bob(hv)`

   Когда Боб проверял личность Алисы и "ставил штампик", он не знал, чему равен хэш алисиного бюллетеня, так как для этого нужно расшифровать `m`, для чего нужно знать одноразовый ключ Алисы.
4. Когда срок голосования истечёт, Алиса разместит в блокчейне бюллетень `v` вместе с заверенной Бобом хеш суммой `s`. Предполагается, что размещение информации в блокчейне анонимно и не отслеживается.
5. Для определения итогов голосования счетная комиссия загрузит из блокчейна все размещенные там бюллетени. Для верификации бюллетеня `v,s` комиссия вычислит хэш бюллетеня `h = hash(v)` и, зная публичный ключ Боба, вычислит изначальный хэш сообщения `hv = D_bob(s)`. Если `h == hv`, то бюллетень валиден и должен быть учтен при подсчете голосов.

Боб не сможет по опубликованному `v` опознать Алису, ведь он подписывал не `hash(v)`, а зашифрованный хэш `E_alice(hash(v))`. Тем самым обеспечивается анонимность голосования.

Блокчейн должен быть независимым от счетной комиссии. В этом случае никто не вмешается в публикацию голосов. Все голоса будут публично доступны. Это позволяет избавиться от доверия к центральной избирательной комиссии. Любой может проверить все бюллетени, посчитать результат и сравнить с официальным.

Избирательное право и однократность голосования обеспечивается Бобом.

Если мы ему не доверяем, то можем добавить наблюдателей - нескольких независимых аутентификаторов Чарли, Давида и т.п., которые будут проверять списки избирателей и подписывать запросы на голосование параллельно с Бобом. Бюллетень `v` будет считаться валидным, если к нему приложены доказательства `E_charlie(hv)`,`E_david(hv)` и т.п. Разумеется, все аутентификаторы должны позаботиться о защите от DDoS, чтобы гарантировать заверение голоса всем легитимным избирателям.

## Ещё схемы со слепой подписью

На самом деле Алиса может вслепую подписывать у Боба любую строку. Например, она может подписать у Боба одноразовый публичный ключ, а соответствующим приватным ключом подписать заполненный бюллетень. Счетная комиссия будет учитывать только бюллетени, которые были подписаны заверенным ключом. По подписи идентифицировать Алису не получится, так как Боб её публичный ключ в глаза не видел, удостоверив зашифрованный образ.

Можно подписать у Боба не сам ключ, а блокчейн-адрес, с которого будет отправлен заполненный бюллетень. В этом случае Алиса опубликует вместе с бюллетенем заверение адреса, с которого отправлен бюллетень. Счетная комиссия будет учитывать только те бюллетени, в которых адрес подписан Бобом. Опять таки, по адресу Боб не сможет идентифицировать Алису, так как он подписывал не сам адрес, а его зашифрованный образ.

Как-то так.

Comment: Что если один из аутентификаторов сохраняет у себя запечатанный подписанный конверт с привязкой к имени? Когда этот конверт будет получен сервером голосования, он сходит к знакомому аутентификатору и узнает, кто его посылал?

Comment: _"пользователь не может перенести штамп на другой бюллетень"_ - а скопировать файл целиком? Получается, бюллетени в принципе должны быть уникальны?

Comment: Вот как раз ваших недостатков я и хочу избежать. Гос. аудентификатору не будут доверять граждане, а независимому - государство. Так же присутствует техническая и программная возможность сопоставить конверт с голосующим.

Comment: Аутентификаторам вообще не нужно доверять. Важна их независимость - невозможность заверить голос несуществующего избирателя. Если кто-то из них заартачится и откажется заверять голос Алисы, это повод для судебного разбирательства.

Comment: @Qwertiy, после подтверждения бюллетеня конверт выбрасывается. Подтверждённый бюллетень отсылается без конверта, на котором была подпись пользователя. И да, все бюллетени уникальны. Чтобы было менее метафорично и более конкретно, я добавил схему голосования с криптографическими примитивами.

Comment: Сам голос - `E_bob(hv)` - что мешает использовать его дважды? Или каждое подписанное сообщение должно быть уникально и считаем только различные? И как из hv извлекается именно голос v?

Comment: @Qwertiy Голос - это `v`. `E_bob(hv)` - это доказательство легитимности голоса. Наличие `E_bob(hv)` означает, что голос был заверен у аутентификатора. Слепое подписание гарантирует, что Боб, заверяя `hv`, само значение `hv` не видел. Поэтому Боб не сможет по опубликованному `hv` установить, что соответствующий голос принадлежит Алисе. Так как в `v` используется случайная соль `nonce`, то шансы сгенерировать два разных голоса с одинаковым `hv` исчезающе малы. Поменять своё мнение Алиса тоже не сможет, для этого нужно сгенерировать новый `v'` с тем же хэшем.

Comment: Т. е. отдавать надо 2 значения - голос и подписанный хэш. Для деанонимизации надо предъявить `E_bob(E_alice(hv))` и ключ Алисы. Хотя смысла нет, если для подмены подбирать сообщение с тем же хешом. А блокчейн зачем в этой схеме?

Comment: @Qwertiy Блокчейн используется как доверенное публичное хранилище поданных голосов для верификации результатов голосования. Разумеется, предполагается, что блокчейн хостится на независимых узлах или, как минимум, позволяет сторонним узлам скачивать блоки. Независимые узлы могут сами посчитать по блокам голоса и проверить официальные результаты.

Comment: @PakUula, но блокчейн что-то гарантирует только пока считаются новые блоки. Если новые блоки считаться перестали (что по идее должно произойти в конце голосования - добавлять больше нечего), то он какую-либо защиту представлять перестаёт и блоки могут быть пересчитаны. Т. е. не вижу какой-то принципиальной разницы с открытой базой.

Comment: @Qwertiy разумеется, это дань моде. Достаточно в конце сбора голосов опубликовать подписанный CSV со всеми голосами. Единственное преимущество блокчейна - быстрое подтверждение. Без блокчейна Алисе нужно ждать окончания срока голосования, чтобы узнать, что её голос принят. С блокчейном она узнает об этом сразу, как будет финализирован блок с её голосом. В PoS блокчейнах, например из семейства Tendermint, это практически моментально.

Comment: Где в этой схеме **гарания**, что аутентифиуатор сохранит в тайне связь Алисы с предоставленным ей уникальным заверением (хэшем)?

Comment: @avp аутентификатор никаких тайн не хранит. Он заверяет хэш в зашифрованном виде `E_alice(hv)`. После того, как Алиса снимает своё шифрование, Боб не в силах установить связь между `hv` и тем, что он заверял.

Comment: Но аутентификатор же знает, какой хэш он дал Алисе? Что мешает ему вступить в сговор с Бобом?

Answer (score 3):

Не существует. Чтобы подтвердить право голоса, обязательно требуется информация о голосующем.

Но чтобы организовать тайное голосование, можно ввести дополнительный этап разделения голосов и личности изберателя. В реальной жизни эту роль на голосовании выполняет урна, она стирает информацию о том, к кому пренадлежит бюллетень.

К примеру, кто-то подтверждает вашу личность и выдает вам одноразовый токен, вы создаете шифрованный канал с доверенным сервером голосования, отправляете токен и голос, на сервере проверяется, есть ли токен  базе, записывается ваш голос и перемешивается с другими, токен записывается в базу. По завершению сбора голосов на сервере стираются ключи для установки зашифрованного канала.

Конечно проблема в доверии к такому серверу, но она решается наличием наблюдателей.

Comment: Я не отменяю факт регистрации пользователя в системе. Но нужно такое голосование, которое подтвердит личность пользователя, но не сопоставит его выбор. В общем система может проверять пользователя, может считать голоса, но не может сопоставить голос с конкретным пользователем

Answer (score 1):

Не очень криптографическая идея, но приходит в голову сделать нечто типа микшера.

Люди самостоятельно организуются в группы из произвольного числа участников. Рассмотрим группу из n участников.

Каждый участник получает по n ключей, сохраняемых в базе под его именем. Один из них он оставляет себе, а остальные раздаёт по 1 каждому участнику группы.

При голосовании каждый член группы должен предоставить n ключей, полученных всеми участниками группы. Есть подозрение, что можно уменьшить число ключей, но пусть будут все.

Получается, голоса группы можно выделить среди других, но невозможно различить, кому какой голов принадлежит.

Если разделить голосование на несколько этапов, можно сделать динамические размеры групп:

- Регистрация в группах
- Получение ключей каждым участником группы
- Распределение ключей между участниками группы - происходит вне системы
- Приём жалоб на отсутствие ключей - если кто-то не поделился ключом, то он исключается из группы, потом использует только один свой ключ для неанонимного голосования или не участвует в голосовании
- Голосование - каждый голосующий должен предоставить уникальные ключи всех участников группы

Надо ещё как-то обработать ситуацию, что участник раздал нескольким людям один и тот же ключ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122366/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-archdemon).