# Схема шифрования сообщения с невозможностью определения отправителя и получателя

Tags: безопасность, криптография, шифрование

Есть системы шифрования такие как **RSA** где мы можем скрыть содержимое сообщений, передаваемое по незащищенному каналу. Но мы раскрываем отправителя и получателя. **Есть ли такие системы шифрования (Если есть, то можно подробнее), в которых помимо невозможности раскрытия содержимого, также нельзя узнать получателя и отправителя? (Понятно, что отправителя и получателя, какой-то группы).** Также было бы отлично, если бы эта система поддерживала сквозное шифрование, то есть захватив сервер, тоже нельзя было ничего определить.

**На данный момент вижу это как (к примеру 4 пользователя Алиса, Боб, Петя, Марк):**

*Алиса хочет отправить сообщение Бобу*

*Каждый из участников генерирует два ключа(всё стандартно).*

*И каждый промежуток времени, пользователь отправляет на сервер свой открытый ключ привязанный к нику (Это делают все пользователи одновременно)*

*Сервер рассылает эти данные каждому пользователю*

*Пользователь сохраняет нужный ему ключ (выбирая по нужному нику)*

*Через какой-то промежуток времени, пользователь(Алиса в данном случае) отправляет на сервер "закрытое" сообщение. Это все пользователи делают одновременно, если они не хотят отправлять сообщение то отправляют мусор(Про его определение далее)*

*Сервер рассылает это сообщение всем пользователям*

*Каждый пользователь пытается расшифровать это сообщение, если понимает что это не мусор (в сообщение содержится заранее обговоренная комбинация отправителя) то цель выполнена*

**Естественно это решение ужасное и имеет много "особенностей":**

*С увеличением пользователей растет нагрузка на все устройства.*

*Большая задержка в работе.*

*При захвате сервера, можно обманывать пользователя на общение с определенным ником*

*И ещё, ещё...*

Подскажите, можно ли как-то доработать это решение? Какие ещё решения существуют?

**Edit:** Необходима система, схема работы. При которой даже получив доступ к серверу нельзя было узнать сообщения пользователей друг другу, а также сервер не мог представится другим пользователем. У каждого пользователя должен быть только ник(Да любой может создать сколько угодно ников). При этом желательно чтобы сервер ничего не хранил у себя. А также сервер даже не должен знать какой пользователь каким интересуется. Спасибо user *Mike*, да можно передавать данные пользователю для прямого соединения отличная идея. Но тогда сервер сможет понять, кто с кем общался

Comment: Что то я не понял. Ваш пример не соответствует условиям задачи. В примере сервер получает публичные ключи пользователей с никами и рассылает их всем. Но тогда любой получатель сообщений зная каким ключом он расшифровал сообщение знает и кто его послал, так как знает ключ.

Comment: @Mike да, немного не так написал, надо чтобы нельзя было понять кто отправил сообщение со стороны сервера и других пользователей, получатель и отправитель знают друг друга

Comment: А тогда зачем нужен сервер, если два пользователя могут напрямую обменяться ключами и напрямую передавать сообщения (ну или использовать сервер как маршрутизатор, сообщая ему кому передать сообщение) как в протоколе SSL. А если надо что бы промежуточные точки (читай сервер) гарантированно не понимали отправителя и получателя, то смотрите принцип работы сети TOR

Comment: И не понятно зачем в вашем примере какая то одновременность передачи сообщений и зачем мусорные сообщения

Comment: @mike `одновременность передачи сообщений и зачем мусорные сообщения`, чтобы нельзя было сказать с сервера отправляет ли пользователь сообщения или нет. То есть с сервера не должно быть понятно вообще ничего о пользователях

Comment: Так а зачем нужен сервер ?

Comment: @mike `А тогда зачем нужен сервер`, а как узнавать IP адреса получателя и отправителя?

Comment: Так. А что вообще понимается под информацией о том, что Алиса это Алиса ? Вам похоже помимо системы шифрования как таковой нужен еще и некий каталог пользователей по никам ? Опишите в вопросе задачу более точно

Comment: Просто это две отдельные задачи. Ведение каталога пользователей и шифрование. Никто не мешает Алисе узнать у сервера IP Боба и потом посылать ему сообщения сколько душе угодно не используя для этого сервер. И тогда сервер ни как не узнает о факте передачи сообщений, только о том, кто из пользователей чьими именами интересовался. А если сервер просто публикует текущий каталог пользователей с ip, то сервер может и этого факта не знать, что Алисе был нужен адрес Боба

Comment: Ну вместо IP можно публиковать некие другие виды адресов, если требуется маршрутизация поверх IP через посредников, сквозь непробиваемые NAT. Например можете посмотреть принципы работы torrent. Он как раз ведет распределенный каталог пользователей (идентифицируемых по хешу) с возможностью определения конечного адреса пользователя

Comment: @Mike изменил вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132740/discussion-between-artemgh-and-mike).

Comment: Потому в каждую ОС и зашит комплект корневых сертификатов, что иначе от mitm защититься невозможно, а сервер в данном случае - владелец канала.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно подробнее?